# convert Varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can I convert varchar as decimal? I already tried this, but I receive the following error:

> "Function argument value, type, or count is invalid"

The column `adjust2,tax,sss_ee,sss_er,phic` are the columns I'm trying to convert to decimal type.

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT DATER, CODE, ID, REG_HRS, R_OT, RD_OT, RD_8, HOL_OT," &
         " HOL_OT8, ND, ABS_TAR, ADJUST1, GROSS_PAY, CAST(ADJUST2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)), CAST(TAX AS DECIMAL(10,2))," &
         " CAST(SSS_EE AS DECIMAL(10,2)), CAST(SSS_ER AS DECIMAL(10,2)), CAST(PHIC AS DECIMAL(10,2)), NET_PAY, REG_PAY FROM [" & dbfFileName & "]"
```

Comment: This is a SQL question. SQL is SQL, regardless of your choice of application language. This has nothing to do with .NET in general or VB.NET specifically.

Comment: All of the SQL syntax appears correct - what does your table definition look like? Is there any chance your dynamic `dbfFileName` is malformed?

Comment: I'd suggest doing it in SSRS (assuming SQL Server) first and starting with the simplest possible query and building it up.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, this is SQL server, see the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is data issue, you have existing data that cannot be cast to decimal.

use `TRY_PARSE` instead.

```
, COALESCE(TRY_PARSE(ADJUST2 AS DECIMAL(10,2)), 0.00)
```